# Get the name of input file once the file is chosen

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-file-upload

What I want is on clicking a link, the file upload should be triggered and on selecting the file, on place of the link, the name of the uploaded file should appear. And on clicking a button the form should be submitted.

I am able to trigger the file upload. But failed to retrieve its name the same time.

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#uploadFile').click(function(e){
      $('#fileUploadField').click();
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#uploadFile').html($('input[type=file]').val());
     });
});
```

**Form** (I am using Codeigniter):

```
<?php echo form_open("member/uploadphoto","id='photoform'")?>
<a href="#" id="uploadFile">Upload File</a>
<input type="file" name="file" id="fileUploadField" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

and in **CSS**:

```
#fileUploadField{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

So, now on clicking the link *Upload File*, the file upload pop up is coming. But I am not able to show the name of the uploaded file (like in normal file upload).

Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#uploadFile').click(function (e) {
        $('#fileUploadField').click();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#fileUploadField').change(function () {
        $('#uploadFile').text(this.value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click the `a` tag you open the browse window and already set the value of the file input, which hasn't been filled yet. You need to wait for a file to be picked. You can do that with `on('change')`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#uploadFile').click(function (e) {
        $('#fileUploadField').click();
    });
    $('#fileUploadField').on('change', function () {
        $('#uploadFile').html($('input[type=file]').val());
    });
});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29Hc8/)